# Rstudio, how do i insert the column that has lesser value to a table that have more value

Tags: r, sqlite, csv

I have a table that consist of 1 column, and another which have a column that consist

```
A<-                                    |PC1<-
                                       |
Protocol                               |     Protocol
SSDP                                   |     TCP
ARP                                    |     HTTP
TCP                                    |     IGMPv3
HTTP                                   |     LLMNR
BROWSER                                |     MBNS
LLMNR                                  |
NBNS                                   |
DHCPv6                                 |
MDNS                                   |
ICMPv6                                 |
IGMPv3                                 |
HTTP/XML                               |
```

So i want to insert the PC1 table to A and change the 2nd column name eg,

```
Protocol|10.0.0.4|
SSDP    |0       |
ARP     |0       |
TCP     |1       |
HTTP    |1       |
BROWSER |0       |
LLMNR   |1       |
NBNS    |1       |
DHCPv6  |0       |
MDNS    |0       |
ICMPv6  |0       |
IGMPv3  |1       |
HTTP/XML|0       |
```

How do i make it this way?

Comment: I doubt that you are dealing with R `tables`. However, your goal is unclear. Also, missing values in multidimensional data structures are indicated with `NA` in R.

Comment: oops :X okay i mean in this way, i edited it again. Thanks for telling that my goal is unclear haha.

Comment: So, assuming you are dealing with vectors, you want to check `PC1 %in% A`?

Comment: @akrun edited* oops sorry!

Comment: @Roland er it gives [1] FALSE, sorry noob programmer here just started this .

Comment: Then you should consider reading "An Introduction to R" and some tutorials.

Comment: Okay i will start reading thanks alot ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 data.frame(A[,1, drop=FALSE], `10.0.0.4`=(A[,1] %in% PC1[,1])+0, check.names=FALSE)
 #    Protocol 10.0.0.4
 #1      SSDP        0
 #2       ARP        0
 #3       TCP        1
 #4      HTTP        1
 #5   BROWSER        0
 #6     LLMNR        1
 #7      NBNS        0
 #8    DHCPv6        0
 #9      MDNS        0
 #10   ICMPv6        0
 #11   IGMPv3        1
 #12 HTTP/XML        0
```

Or

```
 transform(A, `10.0.0.4`=(A[,1] %in% PC1[,1])+0)
```